# Assign group identifiers to groups of rows falling between rows containing a string in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been given an Excel file in which the end of each group of data is marked by a row that is blank except for one cell which contains a string like "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", and so on. The data belonging to Person 1 are in rows preceding the row containing "Person 1", the data belonging to Person 2 are in the rows between the row with "Person 1" and the row containing "Person 2". This pattern is followed until the end of the file, where the last row contains a cell with "Person 100". To make things even more interesting, the "Person [n]" string is not always in the same column and the number of rows per person can vary. See the toy example below.

```
 df_1 <- data.frame(iv1=c(rbinom(3,1,.4), NA, rbinom(4,1,.4), NA, rbinom(2,1,.4), NA),
            iv2=c(rbinom(3,1,.4), NA, rbinom(4,1,.4), NA, rbinom(2,1,.4), NA),
            iv3=c(rbinom(3,1,.4), "Person 1", rbinom(4,1,.4), NA, rbinom(2,1,.4), "Person 3"),
            dv1=c(rbinom(3,1,.4), NA, rbinom(4,1,.4), "Person 2", rbinom(2,1,.4), NA),
            dv2=c(rbinom(3,1,.4), NA, rbinom(4,1,.4), NA, rbinom(2,1,.4), NA),
            dv3=c(rbinom(3,1,.4), NA, rbinom(4,1,.4), NA, rbinom(2,1,.4), NA))
```

Yields this data frame

```
   iv1 iv2      iv3      dv1 dv2 dv3
1    1   1        0        1   1   0
2    0   0        1        0   0   0
3    1   0        0        1   0   1
4   NA  NA Person 1     <NA>  NA  NA
5    1   1        0        0   1   1
6    1   0        0        0   0   0
7    0   0        0        1   0   0
8    1   0        0        1   1   1
9   NA  NA     <NA> Person 2  NA  NA
10   0   0        0        1   0   0
11   0   1        0        0   0   1
12  NA  NA Person 3     <NA>  NA  NA
```

What I would like to do is create a new column ("Person_ID") that identifies the data belonging to each person, so Person_ID would equal 1 for rows belonging to Person 1, Person_ID would equal 2 for rows belonging to Person 2, and so on, as in the data frame below.

```
  iv1 iv2 iv3 dv1 dv2 dv3 Person_ID
1   1   1   0   1   1   0         1
2   0   0   1   0   0   0         1
3   1   0   0   1   0   1         1
4   1   1   0   0   1   1         2
5   1   0   0   0   0   0         2
6   0   0   0   1   0   0         2
7   1   0   0   1   1   1         2
8   0   0   0   1   0   0         3
9   0   1   0   0   0   1         3
```

I would love a dplyr-based solution, but of course, I'm open to whatever works. Thanks!

Comment: Are the values iv1 : dv3 correct in the expected output?

Comment: Ah! Good catch. I have corrected the target/desired data frame to match those in the source data frame.

Comment: Could you try my suggestion. I think the issue is that the output will change all the time because of  `rbinom`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could do it this way:
The values in `iv1:dv3` do not match because you did not set a seed:

First solution is depending on `NA`s that may interfere with other `NA` data.
The second solution is independent of `NA`s:

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 %>% 
  mutate(Person_ID=cumsum(is.na(iv1))+1) %>% 
  na.omit()
```

```
   iv1   iv2 iv3   dv1     dv2   dv3 Person_ID
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl>
1     0     0 0     0         0     0         1
2     1     1 1     0         1     0         1
3     1     0 0     0         0     0         1
4     1     1 0     0         0     1         2
5     1     1 0     0         0     1         2
6     1     0 0     0         1     1         2
7     0     0 1     1         1     0         2
8     0     0 1     0         0     0         3
9     1     1 0     1         0     0         3
```

Another way could be:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>% 
  mutate(Person_ID = coalesce(iv3, dv1),
         Person_ID = ifelse(str_detect(Person_ID, "Person"), parse_number(Person_ID), NA)) %>% 
  fill(Person_ID, .direction = "up") %>% 
  na.omit()
```

Comment: The first solution will likely work, but I worry about conditioning on is.na, due to the possibility of NAs that resulted from (for example) a person simply not responding to iv1, as opposed to the NAs introduced by creating the "boundary" rows. The second solution addresses that concern perfectly for me. Thanks again!

Comment: The second one is independent of `NA`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>% 
  unite(Person_ID, everything(), sep = ",", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(Person_ID = str_extract(Person_ID, "(?<=Person )[0-9]*")) %>% 
  fill(Person_ID, .direction = "up") %>% 
  slice(-which(rowSums(t(apply(df_1, 1, grepl, pattern="Person"))) == 1))
```

Or another option could be:

```
df_1 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_extract(., "(?<=Person )[0-9]*")),
         Person_ID = coalesce(iv3, dv1)) %>% 
  fill(Person_ID, .direction = "up") %>% 
  select(Person_ID) %>% 
  bind_cols(., df_1) %>% 
  na.omit()
```

Output

```
  Person_ID iv1 iv2 iv3 dv1 dv2 dv3
1         1   0   1   1   1   0   0
2         1   0   0   1   1   0   0
3         1   0   1   1   1   1   0
4         2   1   1   1   0   0   0
5         2   0   0   0   0   1   1
6         2   1   1   0   1   0   0
7         2   1   0   1   0   1   1
8         3   1   1   1   1   0   0
9         3   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

Comment: After thinking about it more, I like that the first one is more general, as one doesn't have to know in advance which column(s) the "Person [n]" string will appear in.

Comment: @M.Todd I was trying to keep it more general as I was assuming that the Person may not always be in the same columns. I also went with the last line in case you had an actual `NA` in another row.